# Search for a given value inside unserialized array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have a serialized array that i have unserialized but i want to search whether a given value exists in that array or not, my array structure which is unserialized is like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slot_id] => 1
            [day] => Mon
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slot_id] => 2
            [day] => Wed
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [slot_id] => 3
            [day] => Thu
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [slot_id] => 4
            [day] => Fri
        )

)
```

I have a loop here where i am getting other data

```
<?php 
  foreach($class_s as $slot){
  $data=$this->manage_model->myfunction();
  $search_array=unserialize($data);
  // I want to check here if $slot->id exist in $search_array and $slot->day exist in $search_array
  {
  }
}
?>
```

Please help to sort out my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_key_exists` to check if the key exists in your array.

Here I am using `foreach` to go through each element in the array

```php
foreach ($search_array as $slot) {
  if (!array_key_exists('id', $slot) || !array_key_exists('day', $slot)) {
    // either id or day does not exist
  }
}
```

Comment: But i want to check for value will it work for value i.e. day and slot_id must match

Comment: That detail was not in your original question at all

Comment: I have specified in my question please check .... whether a given value exists in that array or not

Comment: My answer does exactly that. `array_key_exists` gives you true/false if a given value exists in that array

Comment: I have implemented your code but the control is not going inside if block suppose slot_id =1 and day is MON then i want to return some flag with status true.

Comment: In my code, what's inside the if block means that neither does not exist. You'd want to return the flag status true AFTER the if block, and return status false in the in if block.